# How do I inject the container without rebuilding the pod in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a project that I want to add `debug container` to **a pod or some pods**, but I don't want the pod to be rebuilt. `kubectl patch` can be added but the pod will be rebuilt. Is there any other way to achieve this?

I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Then you are looking for [ephemeral-containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/). It was introduced in k8s `v1.16` as an alpha feature and became beta in k8s `v1.23`.

**Ref:**

- [Debugging with an ephemeral debug container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container).

Comment: Thank you, this feature may not work with v1.18. Is there any other plan?

Comment: This feature will work with v1.18.

Comment: Yes, when I enabled the alpha feature, I could add ephemeral-containers via `kubectl alpha debug`, but when I finished debugging there seemed to be **no way to remove it**

Comment: @moluzhui Yes, you cannot remove it in k8s v1.18. The support for removal is added in v1.23. [Issue Link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/84764)